# Sequence is not generating

Tags: java, mysql, oracle, hibernate

I am trying to use two database connection form persistence API

1. MySql connetion
2. Oracle connection.

Persistence.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<persistence xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" version="2.0"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_0.xsd">

    <persistence-unit name="futurepay">
        <provider>org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence</provider>
        <jta-data-source>jdbc/futurepay</jta-data-source>
        <properties>
            <property name="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect" />
            <property name="hibernate.show_sql" value="true" />
            <property name="hibernate.default_schema" value="futurepay" />
        </properties>
    </persistence-unit>

    <persistence-unit name="bbpcOracle">
        <provider>org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence</provider>
        <jta-data-source>oracle/bbpc</jta-data-source>
        <properties>
            <property name="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.Oracle10gDialect" />
            <property name="hibernate.show_sql" value="true" />
        </properties>
    </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

I am using below two entitymange using jta:

```
@PersistenceContext(unitName = "futurepay", type=     PersistenceContextType.TRANSACTION)
public EntityManager futurePayEntityManager;

@PersistenceContext(unitName = "bbpcOracle", type= PersistenceContextType.TRANSACTION)
public EntityManager bbpcPayEntityManager;
```

In the below class I am using bbpcEntityManager:

```
public class SapfiPostionDAOImpl extends GenericDAOImpl implements ISapfiPostionDAO {
        private static final Logger LOGGER = Logger.getLogger(SapfiPostionDAOImpl.class);   

        @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
        @Override
        public List<ShygSapPostHeader> getCustomerFileReqDtls(int statusId) {
            LOGGER.info("getCustomerFileReqDtls");
            List<ShygSapPostHeader> resultList = new ArrayList<>();
            Query query = bbpcPayEntityManager.createNamedQuery("ShygSapPostHeader.getDetails");

            try {
                resultList = query.getResultList();
            } 
            catch (Exception e) {
                LOGGER.info("Exception occured while fetching data from ShygSapPostHeader"+e);
            }

            return resultList;
        }
    }
```

I am using some table for mysql and some from oracle. In oracle table I used sequence generator.

For example :

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "SHYG_SAP_POST_HEADER")
@NamedQueries({
  @NamedQuery(name = "ShygSapPostHeader.getDetails",query="select model from ShygSapPostHeader")
})
@SequenceGenerator(name = "SAP_POSTING_SEQ_GENERATOR", sequenceName = "SAP_POSTING_SEQ", initialValue = 1, allocationSize = 1)
public class ShygSapPostHeader implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "SAP_POSTING_SEQ_GENERATOR")
    @Column(name = "SAP_POST_ID")
    private Long sapPostId;
    @Column(name = "STORE_CODE")
    private String storeCode;
    @Column(name = "REQUEST_DATE")
    private String requestDate;

   .............
   .............
```

But I am getting exception when I am going to deploy this in glassfish.

Exception :

```
Severe: Exception while preparing the app : [PersistenceUnit: futurepay] Unable to build EntityManagerFactory
javax.persistence.PersistenceException: [PersistenceUnit: futurepay] Unable to build EntityManagerFactory
    at org.hibernate.ejb.Ejb3Configuration.buildEntityManagerFactory(Ejb3Configuration.java:892)
    at org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence.createContainerEntityManagerFactory(HibernatePersistence.java:73)
    at org.glassfish.persistence.jpa.PersistenceUnitLoader.loadPU(PersistenceUnitLoader.java:206)
    at org.glassfish.persistence.jpa.PersistenceUnitLoader.<init>(PersistenceUnitLoader.java:120)
    at org.glassfish.persistence.jpa.JPADeployer$1.visitPUD(JPADeployer.java:224)
    at org.glassfish.persistence.jpa.JPADeployer$PersistenceUnitDescriptorIterator.iteratePUDs(JPADeployer.java:495)
    at org.glassfish.persistence.jpa.JPADeployer.createEMFs(JPADeployer.java:233)
    at org.glassfish.persistence.jpa.JPADeployer.prepare(JPADeployer.java:168)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.ApplicationLifecycle.prepareModule(ApplicationLifecycle.java:871)
    at org.glassfish.javaee.full.deployment.EarDeployer.prepareBundle(EarDeployer.java:290)
    at org.glassfish.javaee.full.deployment.EarDeployer.access$200(EarDeployer.java:86)
    at org.glassfish.javaee.full.deployment.EarDeployer$1.doBundle(EarDeployer.java:141)
    at org.glassfish.javaee.full.deployment.EarDeployer$1.doBundle(EarDeployer.java:138)
    at org.glassfish.javaee.full.deployment.EarDeployer.doOnBundles(EarDeployer.java:215)
    at org.glassfish.javaee.full.deployment.EarDeployer.doOnAllTypedBundles(EarDeployer.java:224)
    at org.glassfish.javaee.full.deployment.EarDeployer.doOnAllBundles(EarDeployer.java:250)
    at org.glassfish.javaee.full.deployment.EarDeployer.prepare(EarDeployer.java:138)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.ApplicationLifecycle.prepareModule(ApplicationLifecycle.java:871)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.ApplicationLifecycle.deploy(ApplicationLifecycle.java:410)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.ApplicationLifecycle.deploy(ApplicationLifecycle.java:240)
    at org.glassfish.deployment.admin.DeployCommand.execute(DeployCommand.java:389)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$1.execute(CommandRunnerImpl.java:348)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl.doCommand(CommandRunnerImpl.java:363)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl.doCommand(CommandRunnerImpl.java:1085)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl.access$1200(CommandRunnerImpl.java:95)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$ExecutionContext.execute(CommandRunnerImpl.java:1291)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$ExecutionContext.execute(CommandRunnerImpl.java:1259)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.AdminAdapter.doCommand(AdminAdapter.java:461)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.AdminAdapter.service(AdminAdapter.java:212)
    at com.sun.grizzly.tcp.http11.GrizzlyAdapter.service(GrizzlyAdapter.java:179)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.HK2Dispatcher.dispath(HK2Dispatcher.java:117)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper$Hk2DispatcherCallable.call(ContainerMapper.java:354)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper.service(ContainerMapper.java:195)
    at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.invokeAdapter(ProcessorTask.java:860)
    at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.doProcess(ProcessorTask.java:757)
    at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.process(ProcessorTask.java:1056)
    at com.sun.grizzly.http.DefaultProtocolFilter.execute(DefaultProtocolFilter.java:229)
    at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.executeProtocolFilter(DefaultProtocolChain.java:137)
    at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.execute(DefaultProtocolChain.java:104)
    at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.execute(DefaultProtocolChain.java:90)
    at com.sun.grizzly.http.HttpProtocolChain.execute(HttpProtocolChain.java:79)
    at com.sun.grizzly.ProtocolChainContextTask.doCall(ProtocolChainContextTask.java:54)
    at com.sun.grizzly.SelectionKeyContextTask.call(SelectionKeyContextTask.java:59)
    at com.sun.grizzly.ContextTask.run(ContextTask.java:71)
    at com.sun.grizzly.util.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.doWork(AbstractThreadPool.java:532)
    at com.sun.grizzly.util.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.run(AbstractThreadPool.java:513)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: org.hibernate.MappingException: Could not instantiate id generator [entity-name=com.bbpc.model.ShygSapPostHeader]
    at org.hibernate.id.factory.DefaultIdentifierGeneratorFactory.createIdentifierGenerator(DefaultIdentifierGeneratorFactory.java:117)
    at org.hibernate.mapping.SimpleValue.createIdentifierGenerator(SimpleValue.java:177)
    at org.hibernate.impl.SessionFactoryImpl.<init>(SessionFactoryImpl.java:257)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:1385)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.AnnotationConfiguration.buildSessionFactory(AnnotationConfiguration.java:954)
    at org.hibernate.ejb.Ejb3Configuration.buildEntityManagerFactory(Ejb3Configuration.java:883)
    ... 46 more
Caused by: org.hibernate.MappingException: Dialect does not support sequences
    at org.hibernate.dialect.Dialect.getSequenceNextValString(Dialect.java:668)
    at org.hibernate.id.SequenceGenerator.configure(SequenceGenerator.java:97)
    at org.hibernate.id.SequenceHiLoGenerator.configure(SequenceHiLoGenerator.java:64)
    at org.hibernate.id.factory.DefaultIdentifierGeneratorFactory.createIdentifierGenerator(DefaultIdentifierGeneratorFactory.java:110)
    ... 51 more
```

If I remove the sequence generator portion from the class then its working fine. But I need sequence generator.

So why this exception is coming when I am using sequence generator?

Comment: The error message relates to the futurepay persistence unit, which is based on MySQL. MySQL does not support sequence generators. It seems that com.bbpc.model.ShygSapPostHeader is associated with futurepay and not with bbpcOracle.

Comment: I know MySQL does not support sequence generator. How can I solve this issue?

Comment: How to map those class with bbpcOracle?

Comment: You have to use the correct EntityManagerFactory type object with it. You probably have 2 such objects in your code, one for futurepay and one for bbcp.

Comment: I have used it very correctly. But still getting the error

Comment: Your code does not show how you have done it, so it is difficult to help you any further.

Comment: Please check my update question. I define those entitymanager one class and extend this class.

Comment: This does not tell us which one is SHYG_SAP_POST_HEADER is mapped to.

Comment: Added the method from where I am using bbpcEntityManager